# uploading emails from outlook-2010 to The server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, pop3

I've accidentally kept the default settings when I were installing Outlook 2010 which states under Delivery option leave a copy of messages on the server unchecked

now I have all my E-mails on my laptop but never on my phone because outlook have deleted all the mails

how to import a backup from outlook to the server ? I know how to use python flask if there's a way in flask that would be perfect.

i can't find anything like that over the internet .

Comment: What is "The server"?  Your work email?  gmail?  Something else?  Does it accept IMAP?  If it does perhaps you can just set up IMAP and copy/paste similarly to this : https://www.howtogeek.com/198559/how-to-import-your-pop3-emails-into-an-imap-account/

Comment: You can try selecting the option "leave a copy of messages on the server " again and then restart Outlook to see if all messages will be synced to the server. Besides, it is recommended to use IMAP if you want to access emails on multiple clients.

Comment: @lx07 it does accept imap but it was not setup that way , iam sure that the server has. Cpanel and finally yes a work email

Comment: @perry that didn't work

Comment: Normally, the option "leave a copy of messages on the server " should work. Have you tried restarting Outlook after enabling the option?